# How to retrieve data loss caused by an updated iOS app with incorrect CoreData schema

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

A mistake made to CoreData schema causes users with data using previous schema to no longer see the data after they upgrade their iOS app.  What's the best way to recover the previous data?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using lightweight migration the new schema replaces the original schema.  The original data is no longer a part of the database after the migration.

You can release a new version with the original the original schema for those who haven't upgraded yet.  For those that have you can use `NSMigrationManager` to migrate them back.  Once everyone is  on the old schema again you can release a version with the new schema correctly.

Comment: Thank you Richard. What's the best way to determine who has upgraded to the new schema and who has the original?

Comment: If you've set the model versions you can do it like this:     NSDictionary *metadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:@"" URL:urlParam error:error]; NSArray *modelVersionArray = [metadata objectForKey:NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiersKey]; NSString *modelVersion = [modelVersionArray objectAtIndex:0];